# What is does "SLP_LAN#" option in the bios mean?

Tags: bios, lan

In my BIOS there is an option called "SLP_LAN# Low on DC Power" and it has two choices (enable/disable). what does this option do?

Comment: I would refer to the manual that comes with your motherboard.

Comment: "This can be used to gate power rails that do not need to be on when host WoL [Wake on LAN] and manageability hardware are disabled." -- https://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/BIOS/141-HW-E877_BIOS_Guide.pdf

Comment: Just to add a tiny bit of clarification: "gate" here means "turn off".